# How to hide bottom panel in GNOME?

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel

I want to hide bottom panel so that I would be able to show it again when I want. In the *properties* menu of the panel there is an option for Autohide but not hide totally.

The reason I need it, is because I am using Docky panel and it now it is behind the bottom panel and looks like awful.

What I am doing right now is I am deleting it totally by right clicking on the panel. And the only way I know to return it back is executing following command in the terminal.

```
rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/panel
```

Any other solutions?

Comment: If you have removed it, you can add it again by right clicking the top panel, and clicking new panel. You can then add the applets you want to the bottom panel again. Tedious, but at least it does the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enable buttons to hide the panel whenever you want - if you don't want to delete the panel altogether:

[image] → [image]

To do this, right click the panel, select *Properties* and check **Show hide buttons**

[image]

Comment: He is not looking for the hide button, but how to reduce the size of a auto-hidden panel.

Comment: Are you sure about that? He writes: "...so that I would be able to show it again when I want".

Comment: "...there is an option for Autohide but hide totally not." Imho and afaik this refers to the 6 pixels which remain to be displayed (in older versions of Gnome) even if the panel is auto-hidden.

Answer (score 4):

Are you maybe using an older Ubuntu version? I wrote a Gnome patch a long time ago, which changed the standard auto hide size to 0/1 pixel. At least the last two Gnome versions should ship with that patch.

Of course you can also change it manually:

- Open the application `gconf-editor`. If you don't have it, install it.
- Go to `/apps/panel/toplevels/bottom_panel_screen0`
- Change the value `auto_hide_size` to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best way to hide the gnome panel:

1. Install compiz and ccsm
2. Open ccsm and enable the "widget layer" feature
3. In the widget layer options, go to "behaviour" tab
4. Add the line `name=gnome-panel` in the field `widget windows`
5. Close ccsm

Once this is done you will see the gnome panels only when you display the widget layer.
the default key for this is <kbd>F9</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type `gconf-editor`
3. Browse to apps/panel/toplevels/panel_1/monitor
4. Set value to -6
5. Finish

Answer (score 0):

I simply recommend to remove the bottom panel. Docky replicates the full functionality of the bottom panel, so you do not need it.